# What differentiates style, theme, attr and textApperance when applying styles in XML?

Tags: android

In Android, you can apply style to an XML element in 4 different ways:

1. By `style` attribute — `style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"`
2. By `theme` attribute  — `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"`
3. By `attr` — `android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"`
4. By `textAppearance` attribute — `android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceListItem"`

What is the difference between them and how to pick the right one?